# Maven Dependency - Exclude dependency from a module when it is imported to another project

Tags: maven

I have two projects, `projectA` and `projectB`.  `projectA` is built as a library to be imported into other projects, and `projectB` is a business application that pulls in `projectA`  The project is structured as follows:

```
projectA
|
|->projectA_moduleA
|
|->projectA_moduleB
|
|->projectA_moduleC
```

moduleA has moduleB and moduleC as a dependency, and moduleB has moduleC as a dependency.  In `ProjectB`, I am setting `moduleA` as a dependency when I build.  ModuleB and C have some dependencies that break `projectB`, so I've gone through and excluded that dependency from the moduleB and C import in moduleA, and excluded it from moduleC in moduleB's import (confusing, I know).  However, even after all of this, this dependency that breaks my other project is sneaking it's way in transitively and I can't figure out how to remove it.

The obvious solution would be to remove the dependency in the build process of `projectB`, but I want to make `projectA` easily imported, without having to add these exclusions.  Is there a way in my moduleA pom to declare any import of a certain DEPENDENCY to be ignored?

Comment: Think I should make a point, I want to know if there is a way specifically in `moduleA` to remove any transitive dependency, so that this dependency won't show up in `projectB`

Comment: So why do moduleB and moduleC have these dependencies in the first place?